# How to change the excel function separator ";" to ","?

Tags: excel, function

In my Excel, I have to use `if(a=b;1;0)`.

But I want to use `if(a=b,1,0)`.

How could I change it?

My OS is Mac OS.

Comment: Which version? Maybe [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=60749) could help?

Comment: try this.... http://superuser.com/questions/496614/function-argument-delimiter-excel-2011-for-mac-os-x

Comment: after applying this change to your oS regional settings,l you probably have to restart Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your regional settings. I am not sure how it is done in Mac OS. Check for it and change list separator from ";" to ","

Comment: Yes. This is in fact how it is done on Mac OS. You can change the regional settings in: Settings --> International --> Formats. In here you can set the default decimal seperator for numbers to "," instead of ".". This will change the way formulas are applied. But this will - of course also change the decimal settings on all other apps on your machine.

Comment: No matter how regional setting changes, the excel function argument seperator keeps still. I want to change ";" to "," in excel.

Comment: I have just tried it on my own Mac (OS 10.8.4 and Excel 2011) and the separators does indeed change with the regional separator settings.

Comment: FYI the Excel app needs to be quit (not just closed) & restarted after changing the decimal separator in settings. there is no setting for "list separator" per se, that is implied by the availability of comma if comma is not set as the decimal separator for numbers nor for currency

Answer (score 0):

It's tied to the language setting of the OS.  If you change it at that level, it will be changed in Excel as well.

Comment: My default language is Chinese. I change it into English, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @elixiao maybe you're not doing it right?  Here is a link w/ step by step instructions: http://blogmines.com/blog/2011/11/29/how-to-change-decimal-separator-on-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: My default setting is decimal "." and thousands ",". But this setting has nothing to do with the function argument seperator ";" in excel.