# How do I assign a value when rows header and column headers are matched in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have 400 columns and rows headers on my table. You can imagine this as a matrix with blank values. Need to assign a value where the column and row headers are same. Like column A to A then assign a value 6 A to B assign a value 10.

Example

[image]

Can anybody help me get this output?

SQL answers greatly appreciated if not Excel functions will also work.

Comment: How does a row have a string value?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your formatting makes this impossible to understand.

Comment: 400 columns and 400 rows? What does _the index values are blank and need to assign a value_ mean?? Now from where did you even get 6 and 10?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. As posted this question does not make any sense. All is not lost however, you can improve this. [Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: This is sooo not what a relational database should be used for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have a value, say 6 (like your example) that appears when the column and row names are the same, and have a different value (again, from your example, 10) you can do something like this:

Make sure the column names are in Row 1, and row names are in Column A (or adjust my formula to match your first cell's headers) and you can put

```
=IF($A2=B$1, 6, 10)
```

in cell B2, then drag across the top and down. Let me know if this helps! I might not have understood the question properly.

Comment: Yes sir, that is the answer I am looking for MS Excel. It works. Do you know how to write this in MS SQL ? @notamathmajor

Comment: I don't. I'm not sure if SQL will even let you interact with the literal _name_ of a record or field in a query.

Comment: I would remove the `$` for A column as `IF(A2=$B1; 6; 10)`

Comment: @Sami if you remove the $ from $A, then the formula wont copy across properly.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, also I don't think MS Excel use `,` (mybe in french version) but use `;` instead. Cause I'm sure in English and Arabic versions it use `;`, so it should be `=IF($A2=B$1; 6; 10)`

Comment: Excel uses `,` parameter separators, @Sami. Just like T-SQL.

Comment: @Larnu It's because the regional settings, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/17897946/6426692.

Comment: @Sami Default for English is `,`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is hard coded, and creates the table, but:

- Does it do what you want? Yes
- Is it efficient? Oh no.
- Does it scale? No, but you could *easily* alter it do be.
- Should you really be getting your RDBMS do this? Definately not.

Enjoy:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT TOP 400
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2
         CROSS JOIN N N3)
SELECT @SQL = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.InsaneTable (' +
              STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(10) +
                            N'                              ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Column',I)) + N' int DEFAULT 10'
                     FROM Tally
                     FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,32,N'') + ');';         
SELECT @SQL; --Your debugging friend. Not PRINT as we are way over 4,000 characters
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT TOP 400
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2
         CROSS JOIN N N3)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(10) + N'INSERT INTO dbo.InsaneTable (' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N') VALUES (6);'
                     FROM Tally Ty
                          JOIN sys.columns c ON c.column_id = Ty.I
                          JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                     WHERE t.[name] = 'InsaneTable'
                     FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,1,N'');
SELECT @SQL; --Your debugging friend. Not PRINT as we are way over 4,000 characters
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.InsaneTable;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.InsaneTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have one column (likely the first or second) containing the so called 'row header' as sql tables do not have row names or headers.

Assuming that this 'row header' column is named "column_a" and the first header is for example sake "header_a" then a query similar to the following should suffice:

```
select  column_a, 
(case when header_a = column_a 
then 6 else header_a end) from table
```

This may not be the best solution for your question. If you are able to clarify what is meant by row header perhaps a better solution can be suggested.